# How to increase minimum interation in BigQuery ML

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I've tried out ML functions and only 2 iterations are made, I've started reading how to set more iterations but only max iterations are configurable.

Is there a way to be able to have mininum iterations?
Btw is there an augmenting feature that lets you to generate training data?

Also what numbers should we try for l1_reg and l2_reg to improve an accuracy of 56%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the number of iterations:

1- You need to set the number of iterations using max_iterations (the default is 10 so you don't need to change this for now).

2- Set min_rel_progress to a number that is less than the loss improvements between two consecutive iterations. You can set that to 0.0001.

Without seeing your data and use case it is hard for me to say what should l1_reg and l2_reg be and in general why you are getting low accuracy. My general guess is that you do not have good training data or good features.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set early_stop to false, so that BQML will run max_iterations iterations (default is 20).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the training stopped is probably because the model is not converging and the training/evaluation loss is increasing after iteration.

JiaXun Wu's answer will allow the training continues even if the model is not converging.

You can also check if you have fill in null values yourself. I haven't found documentation regarding how null values are handled by BQML, but for my models, it failed to converge using default null value fill in method.